# How to increase memory in windows form application (Memory Stream)

Tags: c#, winforms, memorystream

After implementing these codes below, I got the "Out of Memory" error. I am really new to this and would like to ask how and where do i increase the memory space of the program.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Background from Employee where EmployeeName = @Name", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txt_name.Text);
                con.Open();
                var dt = new DataTable();


                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dt.Load(dr); // fill DataTable from reader
                }

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Rows[0]["Background"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Background"]))
                    {
                        this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(ms);
                    }
                    // do another stuff
                }
                else
                {
                    // do another stuff
                }
            }con.Close();
```

Any help you would greatly appreciated

Comment: Does it happen the very first time, or just after a while?  That error doesnt always mean RAM, but can mean resources/handles because your app is leaking

Comment: @Plutonix it happens the very first time when the code is implemented

Comment: Most likely the data stored does not represent a valid bitmap or is corrupt.  A) You dont need to fill a datatable, you could get the bytes from the DataReader, b) Note that you have a `new Bitmap()` that means the **old Bitmap** needs to be disposed

Comment: You need to keep the MemoryStream open till the lifetime of the Bitmap. remove the using statement around MemoryStream

Comment: @Kalyan and a using statement around a MemoryStream isn't really needed anyway (since it uses a byte array internally, as opposed to unmanaged resources).

Comment: Thanks guys got it to work as intended just as @kalyan suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Background from Employee where EmployeeName = @Name", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txt_name.Text);
            con.Open();
            var dt = new DataTable();


            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dt.Load(dr); // fill DataTable from reader
            }

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Rows[0]["Background"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Background"]))
                {
                    this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(ms);
                }
                // do another stuff
            }
            else
            {
                // do another stuff
            }
        }con.Close();
```

Credit to Kalyan